# Need help compiling user inputted code

Tags: java, input, compilation, applet

I am in need of assistance, (Using NetBeans 7.4)

I am creating a Programming applet, and I want the end user to answer some questions I will have in the applet.

Is there any way I can have the users inputted "code" (answer to the question) compiled and printed out through the GUI. (User inputs answer, submits, it compiles, and my application prints out if it is right or wrong)

Example: The user needs to answer

```
How do I print out "Hello" in java?
```

and they would have to put

```
"System.out.println("Hello");"
```

Any help would be fantastic,

Thank you in advance,

Comment: The answer is "yes, it's possible", but it's an incredibly broad thing to ask.  It ultimately depends on how you're going to work out recognizing a "correct" answer, which is a discussion that is a fair bit too broad for a place such as Stack Overflow.

Comment: Is it worth just having the user input the answer, and I have it compared a premade string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's possible, but you need to define the set of valid answers for each question, for example you point

```
System.out.println("Hello");
```

as valid answer, but

```
System.out.print("Hello");
```

or

```
System.out.printf("%s", "Hello");
```

just to mention a few, are also valid from a code compilation point of view.

Also you need to clearly define what is a right or a wrong answer, for example should the output have a new line at the end or not, i.e. `println` vs. `print`.

Those are only a few questions who complex and broad the problem is. Not to mention the human understanding of what a correct answer is.

To minimize all this complexity I would suggest to ask precise questions and when code is submitted compile and **run** it and **compare** with the **expected result**. To take your example I would ask

> How do I print out "Hello" to **standard output** in java?

Then you will have to run the code in separate process, given it compiles correctly, and read the `stdout` of that process. After that you may choose to trim the result and compare with the expected result. If matched then the use did input 'a code' which produces to a valid output.

This way your program will validate all above print statements as correct.

To compile user entered code you may use the [Interface to invoke Java™ programming language compilers from programs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html).

To compile other code than java you will need the their compiles installed too which you can also run from java program, if you want to validate `C` code you will need for example `GCC` installed.

Comment: I am currently just writing it for Java language lessons, so it would just be 

`System.out.println("Hello")`

If I wanted to just have the code compiled from their answer is that possible?

Such as if I ask them to answer the question as mentioned about, they would answer with: `System.out.println("Hello")`, it would then compile and say if the code was correct or not, If that makes any sense?

Comment: I think I'll set it up to have multiple answers as you mentioned in your comment, thank you for your time, I shall keep this in mind and post back if I need help :)

Comment: @MarkLang Yes, it is possible to compile java code from java program, please have a look at the link to the I posted, also you have to make sure the that you wrap the answer in such a way you that you can compile it, for example, the answer `System.out.println("Hello")` needs a semicolon to complete a valid statement, after that, a valid statement alone cannot be compiled successfully, you will need an enclosing method which itself needs an enclosing class. If you have problems with implementing the compilation please post a new question with the code you have so far and you'll get helped.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I have figured out a different way of doing it, I am just comparing strings instead of compiling the users code, you may mark this as solved

Comment: @MarkLang You're welcome! You already marked the answer as accepted :) I just didn't want to leave your comments unanswered.